# Error while writing the content of a file to another in scala

Tags: scala

Hello can any one help me how to solve this error i tried in many ways but in vein

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.io._
object test1
{
def main(args: Array[String])
{
    val a=Source.fromFile("pg1661.txt").mkString
    val count=a.split("\\s+").groupBy(x=>x).mapValues(x=>x.length)
    val writer=new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"))
    writer.write(count)
    writer.close()

}
}
```

but it is showing error @write(count) and the error is

```
Multiple markers at this line
- overloaded method value write with alternatives: 
  (java.lang.String)Unit <and> (Array[Char])Unit <and> (Int)Unit cannot be 
  applied to (scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int])
- overloaded method value write with alternatives: 
  (java.lang.String)Unit <and> (Array[Char])Unit <and> (Int)Unit cannot be 
  applied to (scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int])
```

kindly help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: writer.write(count **toString** )

Answer (score 1):

```
writer.print(count.mkString)
```

this would work in the sense that items get written to the file

```
for (i <- count.keys.toList.sorted ) 
     writer.println(i.mkString, count.get(i).mkString)
```

might look a bit nicer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print in a more key-value style then try

```
count.foreach{ case (key, value) => writer.println(s"$key: $value") }
```

Comment: @user2401547 are you using scala 2.9.x or below? The `s"..."` (string interpolation) syntax is only available in scala >= 2.10. Below 2.10 you would need: `writer.println("%s: %s".format(key, value))`.

Comment: Thank you alex actually i was using scala 2.9.1

Comment: @user2401547 Then in addition to gourlaysama's method you can use string concatenation `key + ": " + value`